# Set correct output paths for mix generated asset files in Laravel/Vue project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I can't get my auto generated assets to the right directory.

I have these files in my Laravel project:

- `<laravel-root>/resources/js/app.js` (initializes vue app)
- `<laravel-root>/resources/css/app.scss`
- `<laravel-root>/webpack.config.js`
- `<laravel-root>/webpack.mix.js`

My goal is to have asset files like these:

- `<laravel-root>/public/js/<random_name>.js`
- `<laravel-root>/public/css/<random_name>.css`

My `webpack.mix.js` looks like the following:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.version();


// JS
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

// CSS
mix.sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css').options({
    postCss: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ],
});
```

Also, I use dynamic view loading from VueJS routes:

```
const TodoView = () => import('@pages/TodoView');

export const routes = [
     { name: 'todo', path: '/todo', component: TodoView },
     ...
]
```

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({})
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

But it's not generating the files as I expect. It's generating these files:

- `<laravel-root>/public/css/app.css` (unfortunately no random name)
- `<laravel-root>/public/js/resources_js_pages_TodoView_vue.js`
- `<laravel-root>/public/0af1b2b5f7c13a3a.js` (why not in `public/js/`?)
- `<laravel-root>/public/index.html` (whats this for and how do I remove it?)
- `<laravel-root>/public/mix-manifest.json`

Manifest looks like:

```
{
    "/0af1b2b5f7c13a3a.js": "/0af1b2b5f7c13a3a.js?id=80aa05595369afc7ce9cd0c180e0d6de",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=0fd5a172ff6fa7fa8beaa3493901048f"
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I achieve my expectations? I tried playing around with paths but now I'm out of ideas.
Thank you for help!